# Is there a way to get copy & paste to be context-aware wrt whitespace and formatting?

Tags: text-editing, copy-paste, formatting

When I copy a word and paste it at the end of an existing sentence (between the last word and the full stop), I'd like it to be pasted in such a way that the space between the pasted word and the previously last word is automatically inserted.  Similarly, when I copy a word with spaces around the words, I'd like the spaces to be automatically removed if they are not necessary (i.e. if there would be too many).  Basically, I always want a properly formatted text without having to think about white spaces (similar to [typo-mode](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/typoel)). Does something like this exist?  For context, I'm using evil but I suppose this would also be useful for users of plain Emacs.

Comment: This sounds like something you might use advice for on copy and paste functions. I have tried this for copying overlays here:

https://github.com/jkitchin/scimax/blob/master/ov-highlighter.el#L713

It might give you some ideas.